# Computing hom sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $\mu_{m}$ and $\mu_{p}$ be the group scheme representing the roots of unity over a field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Assume that $p$ divides $m$.

What does one compute the sheaf $\operatorname{Hom}( \mu_{m}, \mu_{p})$?

Are there any reference for similar computations?

Comment: By Cartier duality.